# Connect to check proxy status by using Curl

Tags: php, curl, proxy

Let's say i have this proxy: 222.74.98.234

Ports : 80, 8080, 443, 1080 (http and stock4/5 ports)

Now i'm trying to connect by using this proxy with a list of those ports to see if each port connection was successful or not.

To give me output to be something like that:

```
222.74.98.234:80 - ok 
222.74.98.234:8080 - bad 
222.74.98.234:443 - ok 
222.74.98.234:1080 - bad
```

I have tried almost of every answers which i found here, and currently i'm using [this codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557251/php-how-to-make-sure-if-a-curl-multi-proxy-connection-was-succesful)

But this not exactly what i want, i tried with fsockopen and socket but they slow and i don't have enough experience with curl

Could anyone help me please?

Thanks

Comment: For which cases the above mentioned code is working for you, and in which - not?

Comment: It works with http ports only not stock4/5

Comment: Try to add an option to curl for sock5 version `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);`

Comment: @Alexander So i should add curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy) and curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5) both of them?

Comment: Yes - both, but add option `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5)` only for socks5