# Is possible set multiple proxies or create a DNS pool?

Tags: php, proxy

I use a rotating proxy server, with only one IP:port

Here is my code for proxy use

```
$proxy = 'isp.url.com:port';
$proxyauth = 'marc991231232914:k2gg09128jd06TP';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxyauth);
```

But it only works for one proxy.
Does have some way to use a list of proxies, or create a dns server likely no-ip or something else to avoid this problem?

Proxy is really usefully, don't know why do not have many topics about this

Comment: If you tweak it a bit it will work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557251/php-how-to-make-sure-if-a-curl-multi-proxy-connection-was-succesful

Comment: Wow, it could works... nice thx!!

Comment: But about make a self rotating proxy server, do you know anything about?