# Min width image scraper

Tags: php, web-scraping

I'm using an image scraping feature developed here: https://github.com/morshedalam/url-scraper-php

They are using this regular expression to find images:

```
private $img_expression = '/<img[^>]+src=([\'"])?((?(1).+?|[^\s>]+))(?(1)\1)/';
```

This is fine, however, it returns every single image (including tiny ones). Much like Pinterest, Facebook etc. I'm only interested in getting images that serve as thumbs i.e width > 200px. I realize that the dimensions of an image might not be defined in the html source.

How would you do this?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download the extracted images, get their size and select those that are large enough.

Interestingly, there's an SO answer just for that: [php get all the images from url which width and height >=200 more quicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035954/php-get-all-the-images-from-url-which-width-and-height-200-more-quicker)