# Multiple cURL Connections

Tags: php, curl

I need to make about 20 connections as fasas posable, but curl is just slowing it down. It seems like I need to thread each connection(I don't think you can do that in PHP). There is about a 10 second loading time on each page, and they all seem add up, even though I use curl_multi_exec. Can anyone help me?

Comment: See : [php - Fastest way to check presence of text in many domains (above 1000)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12891689/php-fastest-way-to-check-presence-of-text-in-many-domains-above-1000/12893559#12893559)  or See : [php get all the images from url which width and height >=200 more quicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035954/php-get-all-the-images-from-url-which-width-and-height-200-more-quicker/10036599#10036599)

Comment: Also check speed connection to a sites. If slow speed it always be slow

Comment: If they add up, you're doing it wrong. curl_multi is complicated and poorly documented. Consider non-blocking sockets :) and implement a HTTP client from scratch.