# pcntl runs the same code several times, assistance required

Tags: php, fork, pcntl

I am using pcntl in order to speed up a quite heave CLI php script, that consists mostly of a class, that is in charge of sending all of the auto-emailing on my application.

My goal is as following:
I want to assign each process to a certain task, within a foreach loop, the implementation I've used is the one shown in the code example below.

The problem is that once you fork a process, it executes asynchronously, and also gets a copy of the parent's process stack.
**In my case, what happens is that one task simply executes several times,** 
My question is how can I design this script to be smarter in order to avoid such behavior?.

Code:

```
/**
@description this is the main procedure of this class, it iteratates over the relevant tasks and sends the emails using the SendGrid wrapper class
@see SendGridWrapper
@return void
*/
public function execute(){
    if(!isset($this->tasks)){
        throw new exception("Please call getRelevantTasks() prior to trying to execute anything");
    }
$proccesses = array();
foreach($this->tasks as $myTask){
    $pid = pcntl_fork();
    if($pid){
        $proccesses[] = $pid;
    }
    else if($pid == -1){
        die('FORK FAILED, STATUS -1');
    }
    else{   
        if(isset($myTask['recipient_model'])){

            $this->currentModel = $myTask['recipient_model'];
            $lang = $myTask['lang'];
            $classPath = self::$modelsDir . $myTask['recipient_model'] . '.php';
            $className = $myTask['recipient_model'];
            if(!class_exists($myTask['recipient_model'] )){
                require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../' .  $classPath); 
            }
            else if(isset($recipientFetcher)){
                unset($this->model);
                unset($this->mailingList);
                unset($this->substitutionList);
            }
            $this->model = null;
            $this->mailingList = null;
            $this->substitutionList = null;
            $this->model = new $className($myTask['lang']);
            $addresses = $this->model->getMailRecipients();
            if(empty($addresses) || sizeof($addresses) == 0){
                continue;
            }
            $this->model->prepare();
            $this->substitutionList = $this->model->getDynamicParams();

        }
        else{
            throw new exception('No recipient model was found');
        }

        foreach($addresses as $myMail){
            $this->mailingList[$myMail['personal_email']] = $myMail['contact_name'];
        }
        $templatePath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../'; 
        $templatePath .= $lang ? self::$templatesDirEn . $myTask['html_email_path'] : self::$templatesDirHe . $myTask['html_email_path'];
        $html = file_get_contents($templatePath);
        $this->sendMail($html, $myTask['task_schedule_id']);
        echo "model:" . $myTask['recipient_model'];
        echo $this->log;
        $this->log = "";
        die("\r\n Child proccess has been executed successfully\r\n");  

    }   
}
if($pid){
    foreach($proccesses as $key => $val){
         pcntl_waitpid($val, $status, WUNTRACED);
    }
}
```

}

Thanks in advance,
Oleg.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Introduction**

I see you are trying to send mails `$this->sendMail($html, $myTask['task_schedule_id']);` and I think it's a really bad idea trying to use multiple process for this task. You should consider using message queue for this task because emails can be very slow.

**Use a Queue System**

You should be using [Gearman](http://gearman.org/), [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) or [Beanstalkd](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/) for this task. Worst case scenario use Implement your own simple message queue with `memcached`.

Here is a typical Gearman Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855907/when-to-send-auto-email-instantly-on-button-click-or-later

**Quick Fix**

Remove all those code and put it in a function called `execute_worker` where you can push the task to it

```
// Break Task to groups
$tasks = array_chunk(range("A", "Z"), 10);
foreach($tasks as $task) {
    $pid = pcntl_fork();
    if ($pid == - 1) {
        throw new ErrorException('FORK FAILED, STATUS -1');
        break;
    }

    if ($pid == 0) {
        execute_worker($task); // In Child
        exit(); // In Child
    }
}
```

**Using Threads**

You can also use [Worker](http://php.net/manual/en/class.worker.php) or [Thread](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php) in `PHP` with [pThreads](http://pthreads.org/) to speed up processing.

- An easy to use, quick to learn Threading API for PHP5.3+
- Execute any and all predefined and user declared methods and functions asynchronously
- Ready made synchronization included, geared towards the PHP environment
- Yes! Windows support

**Simple Project**

`file_get_contents` is said to be slow when compared with `curl` and no where close to the power of `curl_multi_init` which allows the processing of multiple cURL handles in parallel.

See:

- [php get all the images from url which width and height >=200 more quicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035954/php-get-all-the-images-from-url-which-width-and-height-200-more-quicker)
- [php - Fastest way to check presence of text in many domains (above 1000)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12891689/php-fastest-way-to-check-presence-of-text-in-many-domains-above-1000/12893559#12893559)

Our Objective would be to implement our own **Multi `file_get_contents`** version

**Multi file_get_contents Example**

```
// My Storage
$s = new Storage();

// Threads Storage
$ts = array();

// Total Threads same as total pages
$pages = 100;

// Porpulate Threads (Don't Start Yet)
$i = 0;
while($i ++ < $pages) {
    $ts[] = new Process($s, $i);
}

// Start the timer
$start = microtime(true);

// Lets start all our Threads
foreach($ts as $t) {
    $t->start();
}

// Wait for all threads to compleate
foreach($ts as $t) {
    $t->join();
}

printf("\n\nFound %s in %d pages", number_format($s->total), $pages);
printf("\nFinished %0.3f sec", microtime(true) - $start);
```

**Output**

```
php a.php
3:01:37: 3548 #START    {"page":1}
3:01:37: 7064 #START    {"page":2}
3:01:37: 10908 #START   {"page":3}
3:01:37: 10424 #START   {"page":4}
3:01:37: 11472 #START   {"page":5}
3:01:37: 3876 #START    {"page":6}
3:01:37: 7276 #START    {"page":7}
3:01:37: 11484 #START   {"page":8}
3:01:37: 932 #START     {"page":9}
3:01:37: 11492 #START   {"page":10}
3:01:37: 11500 #START   {"page":11}
3:01:37: 11508 #START   {"page":12}
3:01:37: 11504 #START   {"page":13}
3:01:37: 11512 #START   {"page":14}
3:01:37: 11516 #START   {"page":15}
3:01:37: 11520 #START   {"page":16}
3:01:37: 11524 #START   {"page":17}
3:01:37: 11528 #START   {"page":18}
3:01:37: 10816 #START   {"page":19}
3:01:37: 7280 #START    {"page":20}
3:01:37: 11556 #START   {"page":21}
3:01:37: 11560 #START   {"page":22}
3:01:37: 11564 #START   {"page":23}
3:01:37: 11612 #START   {"page":24}
3:01:37: 11616 #START   {"page":25}
3:01:37: 11600 #START   {"page":26}
3:01:37: 11608 #START   {"page":27}
3:01:37: 11568 #START   {"page":28}
3:01:37: 11452 #START   {"page":29}
3:01:38: 11624 #START   {"page":30}
3:01:38: 11628 #START   {"page":31}
3:01:38: 11632 #START   {"page":32}
3:01:38: 11636 #START   {"page":33}
3:01:38: 11644 #START   {"page":34}
3:01:38: 11648 #START   {"page":35}
3:01:38: 11652 #START   {"page":36}
3:01:38: 11656 #START   {"page":37}
3:01:38: 11660 #START   {"page":38}
3:01:38: 11664 #START   {"page":39}
3:01:38: 11668 #START   {"page":40}
3:01:38: 11672 #START   {"page":41}
3:01:38: 11676 #START   {"page":42}
3:01:38: 11680 #START   {"page":43}
3:01:38: 11684 #START   {"page":44}
3:01:38: 11688 #START   {"page":45}
3:01:38: 11692 #START   {"page":46}
3:01:38: 11696 #START   {"page":47}
3:01:38: 11700 #START   {"page":48}
3:01:38: 11704 #START   {"page":49}
3:01:38: 11712 #START   {"page":50}
3:01:38: 11708 #START   {"page":51}
3:01:38: 11716 #START   {"page":52}
3:01:38: 11720 #START   {"page":53}
3:01:38: 11724 #START   {"page":54}
3:01:38: 11728 #START   {"page":55}
3:01:38: 11732 #START   {"page":56}
3:01:38: 11736 #START   {"page":57}
3:01:38: 11740 #START   {"page":58}
3:01:38: 11744 #START   {"page":59}
3:01:38: 11748 #START   {"page":60}
3:01:38: 11752 #START   {"page":61}
3:01:38: 11756 #START   {"page":62}
3:01:38: 11760 #START   {"page":63}
3:01:38: 11764 #START   {"page":64}
3:01:38: 11768 #START   {"page":65}
3:01:38: 11772 #START   {"page":66}
3:01:38: 11776 #START   {"page":67}
3:01:38: 11780 #START   {"page":68}
3:01:38: 11784 #START   {"page":69}
3:01:38: 11788 #START   {"page":70}
3:01:38: 11792 #START   {"page":71}
3:01:38: 11796 #START   {"page":72}
3:01:38: 11800 #START   {"page":73}
3:01:38: 11804 #START   {"page":74}
3:01:38: 11808 #START   {"page":75}
3:01:38: 11812 #START   {"page":76}
3:01:38: 11816 #START   {"page":77}
3:01:38: 11820 #START   {"page":78}
3:01:38: 11824 #START   {"page":79}
3:01:38: 11828 #START   {"page":80}
3:01:38: 11832 #START   {"page":81}
3:01:38: 11836 #START   {"page":82}
3:01:38: 11840 #START   {"page":83}
3:01:38: 11844 #START   {"page":84}
3:01:38: 11848 #START   {"page":85}
3:01:38: 11852 #START   {"page":86}
3:01:38: 11856 #START   {"page":87}
3:01:38: 11860 #START   {"page":88}
3:01:38: 11864 #START   {"page":89}
3:01:38: 11868 #START   {"page":90}
3:01:38: 11872 #START   {"page":91}
3:01:38: 11876 #START   {"page":92}
3:01:38: 11880 #START   {"page":93}
3:01:38: 11884 #START   {"page":94}
3:01:38: 11888 #START   {"page":95}
3:01:38: 11892 #START   {"page":96}
3:01:38: 11896 #START   {"page":97}
3:01:38: 11900 #START   {"page":98}
3:01:38: 11904 #START   {"page":99}
3:01:38: 11908 #START   {"page":100}
3:01:38: 11508 #END             {"page":12,"byte":1141,"count":155839}
3:01:38: 10424 #END             {"page":4,"byte":1201,"count":553595}
3:01:38: 11516 #END             {"page":15,"byte":1204,"count":119612}
3:01:38: 3548 #END              {"page":1,"byte":1208,"count":6737525}
3:01:38: 11484 #END             {"page":8,"byte":1160,"count":257021}
3:01:38: 11472 #END             {"page":5,"byte":1175,"count":446411}
3:01:38: 10908 #END             {"page":3,"byte":1222,"count":787301}
3:01:38: 11492 #END             {"page":10,"byte":1175,"count":193958}
3:01:38: 11504 #END             {"page":13,"byte":1130,"count":141450}
3:01:38: 11528 #END             {"page":18,"byte":1102,"count":95511}
3:01:38: 11524 #END             {"page":17,"byte":1147,"count":102727}
3:01:38: 11560 #END             {"page":22,"byte":1111,"count":73536}
3:01:38: 11556 #END             {"page":21,"byte":1101,"count":78097}
3:01:38: 11500 #END             {"page":11,"byte":1201,"count":172820}
3:01:38: 932 #END               {"page":9,"byte":1159,"count":222922}
3:01:38: 11520 #END             {"page":16,"byte":1135,"count":110510}
3:01:38: 7064 #END              {"page":2,"byte":1165,"count":1264444}
3:01:38: 11512 #END             {"page":14,"byte":1123,"count":129721}
3:01:38: 11612 #END             {"page":24,"byte":1115,"count":65012}
3:01:38: 11600 #END             {"page":26,"byte":1134,"count":58928}
3:01:38: 7276 #END              {"page":7,"byte":1189,"count":301469}
3:01:38: 10816 #END             {"page":19,"byte":1120,"count":89609}
3:01:38: 11616 #END             {"page":25,"byte":1052,"count":61793}
3:01:38: 3876 #END              {"page":6,"byte":1188,"count":362101}
3:01:38: 7280 #END              {"page":20,"byte":1079,"count":83632}
3:01:38: 11564 #END             {"page":23,"byte":1076,"count":68909}
3:01:38: 11632 #END             {"page":32,"byte":1095,"count":44013}
3:01:38: 11652 #END             {"page":36,"byte":1042,"count":37185}
3:01:38: 11452 #END             {"page":29,"byte":1097,"count":50532}
3:01:38: 11636 #END             {"page":33,"byte":1097,"count":42148}
3:01:38: 11644 #END             {"page":34,"byte":1124,"count":40236}
3:01:38: 11664 #END             {"page":39,"byte":1078,"count":32792}
3:01:38: 11668 #END             {"page":40,"byte":1017,"count":31487}
3:01:38: 11608 #END             {"page":27,"byte":1117,"count":55561}
3:01:38: 11628 #END             {"page":31,"byte":1076,"count":46133}
3:01:38: 11624 #END             {"page":30,"byte":1111,"count":48265}
3:01:38: 11568 #END             {"page":28,"byte":1076,"count":52851}
3:01:38: 11656 #END             {"page":37,"byte":1068,"count":35590}
3:01:38: 11688 #END             {"page":45,"byte":1062,"count":26060}
3:01:38: 11680 #END             {"page":43,"byte":1081,"count":28013}
3:01:38: 11672 #END             {"page":41,"byte":1086,"count":30320}
3:01:38: 11724 #END             {"page":54,"byte":1060,"count":19900}
3:01:38: 11716 #END             {"page":52,"byte":1069,"count":21079}
3:01:38: 11732 #END             {"page":56,"byte":1038,"count":18748}
3:01:38: 11692 #END             {"page":46,"byte":1033,"count":25230}
3:01:38: 11696 #END             {"page":47,"byte":1098,"count":24469}
3:01:38: 11728 #END             {"page":55,"byte":1003,"count":19353}
3:01:38: 11648 #END             {"page":35,"byte":1105,"count":38651}
3:01:38: 11660 #END             {"page":38,"byte":1075,"count":34037}
3:01:38: 11700 #END             {"page":48,"byte":1059,"count":23725}
3:01:39: 11720 #END             {"page":53,"byte":1028,"count":20463}
3:01:39: 11704 #END             {"page":49,"byte":1006,"count":22966}
3:01:39: 11712 #END             {"page":50,"byte":988,"count":22369}
3:01:39: 11676 #END             {"page":42,"byte":1113,"count":29144}
3:01:39: 11748 #END             {"page":60,"byte":1054,"count":17002}
3:01:39: 11684 #END             {"page":44,"byte":1041,"count":26999}
3:01:39: 11756 #END             {"page":62,"byte":1024,"count":16165}
3:01:39: 11760 #END             {"page":63,"byte":1036,"count":15814}
3:01:39: 11740 #END             {"page":58,"byte":1075,"count":17833}
3:01:39: 11736 #END             {"page":57,"byte":1064,"count":18293}
3:01:39: 11752 #END             {"page":61,"byte":1077,"count":16607}
3:01:39: 11708 #END             {"page":51,"byte":1045,"count":21668}
3:01:39: 11768 #END             {"page":65,"byte":1041,"count":15021}
3:01:39: 11764 #END             {"page":64,"byte":1063,"count":15405}
3:01:39: 11744 #END             {"page":59,"byte":1052,"count":17394}
3:01:39: 11800 #END             {"page":73,"byte":1025,"count":12361}
3:01:39: 11792 #END             {"page":71,"byte":1053,"count":13051}
3:01:39: 11796 #END             {"page":72,"byte":1092,"count":12721}
3:01:39: 11784 #END             {"page":69,"byte":1031,"count":13677}
3:01:39: 11780 #END             {"page":68,"byte":1019,"count":13967}
3:01:39: 11772 #END             {"page":66,"byte":1068,"count":14644}
3:01:39: 11816 #END             {"page":77,"byte":1045,"count":11185}
3:01:39: 11804 #END             {"page":74,"byte":1062,"count":12071}
3:01:39: 11824 #END             {"page":79,"byte":1047,"count":10719}
3:01:39: 11820 #END             {"page":78,"byte":1035,"count":10940}
3:01:39: 11788 #END             {"page":70,"byte":987,"count":13354}
3:01:39: 11776 #END             {"page":67,"byte":1036,"count":14278}
3:01:39: 11828 #END             {"page":80,"byte":1013,"count":10519}
3:01:39: 11832 #END             {"page":81,"byte":1052,"count":10318}
3:01:39: 11812 #END             {"page":76,"byte":991,"count":11465}
3:01:39: 11808 #END             {"page":75,"byte":1043,"count":11769}
3:01:39: 11860 #END             {"page":88,"byte":1018,"count":8991}
3:01:39: 11852 #END             {"page":86,"byte":971,"count":9362}
3:01:39: 11868 #END             {"page":90,"byte":1006,"count":8641}
3:01:39: 11840 #END             {"page":83,"byte":1026,"count":9922}
3:01:39: 11872 #END             {"page":91,"byte":980,"count":8464}
3:01:39: 11892 #END             {"page":96,"byte":936,"count":7727}
3:01:39: 11836 #END             {"page":82,"byte":1052,"count":10117}
3:01:39: 11844 #END             {"page":84,"byte":973,"count":9739}
3:01:39: 11864 #END             {"page":89,"byte":1033,"count":8821}
3:01:39: 11856 #END             {"page":87,"byte":994,"count":9169}
3:01:39: 11848 #END             {"page":85,"byte":1040,"count":9544}
3:01:39: 11896 #END             {"page":97,"byte":988,"count":7562}
3:01:39: 11876 #END             {"page":92,"byte":1003,"count":8294}
3:01:39: 11888 #END             {"page":95,"byte":995,"count":7860}
3:01:39: 11880 #END             {"page":93,"byte":1052,"count":8143}
3:01:39: 11900 #END             {"page":98,"byte":977,"count":7418}
3:01:39: 11904 #END             {"page":99,"byte":999,"count":7270}
3:01:39: 11884 #END             {"page":94,"byte":931,"count":8002}
3:01:39: 11908 #END             {"page":100,"byte":977,"count":7144}


Found 14,075,927 in 100 pages
Finished 1.489 sec
```

**Time Taken**

```
Found 14,075,927 in 100 pages
Finished 1.489 sec
```

**Classes Used**

```
class Process extends Thread {

    public function __construct($storage, $page) {
        $this->storage = $storage;
        $this->page = $page;
        // $this->start();
    }

    public function run() {
        $format = "%s: %1u %s\t%s\n";
        $formatTime = "g:i:s";
        $sleep = mt_rand(0, 1); // Just for Demo

        printf($format, date($formatTime), $this->getThreadId(), "#START", "{\"page\":$this->page}");

        // Do something useful
        $data = file_get_contents(sprintf("http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/tags?pagesize=100&page=%s", $this->page));

        // Decode the Data from API
        $json = json_decode(gzdecode($data));

        // Lets Build A profile
        $profile = array();
        $profile['page'] = $this->page;
        $profile['byte'] = strlen($data);

        // Do more work
        $profile['count'] = array_sum(array_map(function ($v) {
            return $v->count;
        }, $json->tags));

        $this->storage->total = bcadd($this->storage->total, $profile['count']);
        // Print Information
        printf($format, date($formatTime), $this->getThreadId(), "#END\t", json_encode($profile));
    }
}

class Storage extends Stackable {
    public $total = 0;

    public function run() {
    }
}
```

**Conclusion**

Did `file_get_contents` just get `100 pages` in just `1.489 sec` with my crappy connection. `Yes` it did. Tested the same code on my live server and It took me less than `0.939 sec` to fetch `200` pages.

Your application can be faster in so many ways you just have to use the right technology at the right place.