# Assessing cURL performance

Tags: php, performance, curl

before redirecting me to other questions concerning cURL performance, please continue reading, I've read most of them.

Anyway : I'm using cURL, namely **curl_multi_exec** . I have to fetch an average of 30 to 60 pages at a time, and so far, it is working perfectly.

But then, lately, I've discovered cURL libraries, two of them actually, **RollingCurl** and **Zebra_cURL** which are both said to be faster, more efficient.

The two of them being rather easy to use, I've tried doing tests to try and figure out which one is faster (even by a second). But so far, it has been inconclusive : "Why", will you ask me ? It is because I use a shared hosting at Hostpapa. The server having its performance ups and downs makes it extremely difficult to know exactly how long a simple script is taking to execute.

For example sake, the same script using curl_multi_exec executed three consecutive times returned three varying times (from 1 to 3 minutes difference).

*I take in account that the website from which I fetch this data can take longer to respond at some times. Yet the performance vary too much.*

My questions are :
- Is there a way, using my own hosting or another service, to see for myself which library is more efficient for my case ?

- If not, then I turn to those who've tried them. Which one of them has given you the best performances ? If you have some statistics they'd be extremely helpful.

Thank you for your patience, and sorry for the lengthy post.
Cordially...
Unforgiven

Comment: You could setup a virtual machine and test it by yourself. Otherwise, you might take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16431346).

Comment: A virtual machine like Wampserver ? But then, it would be even more unstable, seeing as my internet connection is crappy.

Comment: Wampserver isn't a virtual machine. I meant that you could install VirtualBox and install a linux on it and configure it as a webserver. Anyways, you can't do much if you're restrained by your shared hosting. Consider to hire a VPS, it's cheap. Of course, it all depends on the context/situation. Is it worth it ?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not an option. So far, I'm using the shared hosting of a friend because I can't just now afford to buy my own. IS there another option ?

Comment: You can't speed anything up if your network(or your hosting) is slow to begin with.

Comment: Even is it is slow as you say, I aim to nevertheless increase performance even by a small amount. I intend to move to a professional hosting solution in the near future, but I need this now. Anyway, I see that perhaps I'm asking for the impossible.

Comment: Then setup WAMP or a virtualmachine. Instead of fetching external resources, you fetch resources from localhost. You then compare the results. You should know which one is faster.