# curl_multi is very slow to check 100 of urls

Tags: php, curl, curl-multi

I'm using following code to check broken links in the given url. but this process is very slow. i need to speed up this process quickly.

```
$$url_list = array(
"http://goog528le.com",
"http://facebook.com",
"http://google.com", 
"http://youtube.com", 
"http://yahoo.com", 
"http://amazon.com",
"http://baidu.com", 
"http://wikipedia.org", 
"http://live.com",
"http://qq.com", 
"http://taobao.com", 
"http://google.co.in",
"http://twitter.com", 
"http://blogspot.com",
"http://yahoo.co.jp", 
"http://linkedin.com",
"http://bing.com",
"http://sina.com.cn"
, "http://yandex.ru");

// 1. multi handle
$mh = curl_multi_init();
$max_connections = 10;
$dead_urls = array();
$not_found_urls = array();

// 2. add multiple URLs to the multi handle
for ($i = 0; $i < $max_connections; $i++) {
   add_url_to_multi_handle($mh, $url_list);
}

// 3. initial execution
 do {
$mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
```

} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

// 4. main loop
   while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {

```
// 5. there is activity
if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {

    // 6. do work
    do {
        $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
    } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

    // 7. is there info?
    if ($mhinfo = curl_multi_info_read($mh)) {
        // this means one of the requests were finished
        // 8. get the info on the curl handle
        $chinfo = curl_getinfo($mhinfo['handle']);

        // 9. dead link?
        if (!$chinfo['http_code']) {
            $dead_urls [] = $chinfo['url'];

            // 10. 404?
        } else if ($chinfo['http_code'] == 404) {
            $not_found_urls [] = $chinfo['url'];

            // 11. working
        } else {
            $working_urls [] = $chinfo['url'];
        }

        // 12. remove the handle
        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $mhinfo['handle']);
        curl_close($mhinfo['handle']);

        // 13. add a new url and do work
        if (add_url_to_multi_handle($mh, $url_list)) {

            do {
                $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
            } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
        }
    }
}
```

}

// 14. finished
    curl_multi_close($mh);

```
echo "==Dead URLs==\n";
echo implode("\n", $dead_urls) . "\n\n";

echo "==404 URLs==\n";
echo implode("\n", $not_found_urls) . "\n\n";

echo "==Working URLs==\n";
echo implode("\n", $working_urls);

// 15. adds a url to the multi handle
function add_url_to_multi_handle($mh, $url_list)
{
static $index = 0;

// if we have another url to get
if (isset($url_list[$index]) && $url_list[$index]) {

    // new curl handle
    $ch = curl_init();

    // set the url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_list[$index]);
    // to prevent the response from being outputted
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    // follow redirections
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    // do not need the body. this saves bandwidth and time
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);

    // add it to the multi handle
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch);
    // increment so next url is used next time
    $index++;

    return true;
} else {

    // we are done adding new URLs
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: that code will not do anything

Comment: How fast are you looking at ? [Once loaded 100 domains with all their content in 15 sec](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13461652/1226894)

Comment: Mr Baba thanks for replying me. but still not solve my problem. using this also getting late to give the result in some times.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to process each request as soon as it completes. This eliminates the wasted CPU cycles from busy waiting. It's also a good idea to create a queue of cURL requests to allow for maximum throughput. Each time a request is completed, I add a new one from the queue. By dynamically adding and removing links, we keep a constant number of links downloading at all times. This gives us a way to throttle the amount of simultaneous requests we are sending. The result is a faster and more efficient way of processing large quantities of cURL requests in parallel.

Source: [onlineaspect.com](http://www.onlineaspect.com/2009/01/26/how-to-use-curl_multi-without-blocking/)

Here's a function for reference:

```
function rolling_curl($urls, $callback, $custom_options = null) {

    // make sure the rolling window isn't greater than the # of urls
    $rolling_window = 5;
    $rolling_window = (sizeof($urls) &lt; $rolling_window) ? sizeof($urls) : $rolling_window;

    $master = curl_multi_init();
    $curl_arr = array();

    // add additional curl options here
    $std_options = array(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER =&gt; true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION =&gt; true,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS =&gt; 5);
    $options = ($custom_options) ? ($std_options + $custom_options) : $std_options;

    // start the first batch of requests
    for ($i = 0; $i &lt; $rolling_window; $i++) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        $options[CURLOPT_URL] = $urls[$i];
        curl_setopt_array($ch,$options);
        curl_multi_add_handle($master, $ch);
    }

    do {
        while(($execrun = curl_multi_exec($master, $running)) == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
        if($execrun != CURLM_OK)
            break;
        // a request was just completed -- find out which one
        while($done = curl_multi_info_read($master)) {
            $info = curl_getinfo($done['handle']);
            if ($info['http_code'] == 200)  {
                $output = curl_multi_getcontent($done['handle']);

                // request successful.  process output using the callback function.
                $callback($output);

                // start a new request (it's important to do this before removing the old one)
                $ch = curl_init();
                $options[CURLOPT_URL] = $urls[$i++];  // increment i
                curl_setopt_array($ch,$options);
                curl_multi_add_handle($master, $ch);

                // remove the curl handle that just completed
                curl_multi_remove_handle($master, $done['handle']);
            } else {
                // request failed.  add error handling.
            }
        }
    } while ($running);

    curl_multi_close($master);
    return true;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I need all urls responds not only 200. So i edited ur code like follows but it also get more time to give results

Comment: This will also get more time to give results. DO you have other things