# Calculate MD5 of 90,000+ files and store to a database

Tags: php, multithreading, md5

I am working on a script that downloads all of my images, calculates the MD5 hash, and then stores that hash in a new column in the database.  I have a script that selects the images from the database and saves them locally.  The image's unique id becomes the filename.

My problem is that, while [cURLQueue](https://github.com/mattcolf/php-curl-queue) works great for quickly downloading many files, calculating the MD5 hash of each file in a callback slows the downloading down.  That was my first attempt.  For my next attempt, I would like to separate the downloading and hashing parts of my code.  What is the best way to do this?  I would prefer to use PHP, as that is what I am most familiar with and what our servers run, but PHP's thread support is lacking to say the least.

Thoughts are to have a parent process that establishes a SQLite connection, then spawn many children that choose an image, calculate the hash of it, store it in the database, and then delete the image.  Am I going down the right path?

Comment: save file, call md5_file() in a loop - latter

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322901/making-a-large-processing-job-small-er/13393543#13393543 almost the same issue ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to approach this, but which you choose really depends on the particulars of your project.

A simple way would be to download the images with one PHP, then place them on the file system and add an entry to the queue database. Then a second PHP program would read the queue, and process those waiting.

For the second PHP program, you could setup a cron job to just check regularly and process all that are waiting. A second way would be to spawn the PHP program in the background every time a download finishes. The second method is more optimal, but a little more involved. Check out the post below for info on how to run a PHP script in the background.

[Is there a way to use shell_exec without waiting for the command to complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019867/is-there-a-way-to-use-shell-exec-without-waiting-for-the-command-to-complete)

Comment: Ended up solving the problem a different way, but this is a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've covered a similar issue at work, but it will need an amqp server like [rabbitmq](http://www.rabbitmq.com/).

Imagine to have 3 php scripts:

- first: add the urls to the queue
- second: get the url from the queue, download the file and adds the downloaded filename to the queue
- third: get the filename to the queue and sets the md5 into the database

We use such way to handle multiple image download/processing using python scripts (php is not that far).

You can check some php libraries [here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/devtools.html#php-dev) and some basic examples [here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html).

In this way we can scale each worker depending on each queue length. So if you have tons of urls to be downloaded you just start another script #2, if you have lot of unprocessed file you just start a new script #3 and so on.