# High clock speed vs multiple cores/CPUs in a web server

Tags: php, mysql, performance, web, cpu

For a heavy load web server (multiple users/sites), what will you recommend for best performance:

- A dual CPU server with lower per-core clock speed (e.g. the Dual E5-2620 @ 2.0GHz)
  OR
- A single CPU server with higher per-core clock speed (e.g. a E3-1270 @ 3.5GHz)

In a head-to-head compare the E3 seems to be the better choice due to the higher clock speed:
http://cpuboss.com/cpus/Intel-Xeon-E5-2620-vs-Intel-Xeon-E3-1270V2

The server is used to host CPU and IO-intensive PHP applications with a MySQL innodb database. I want to know if this server will be able to benefit from the extra cores, or if I will get better performance/cost with the higher clock?

Thank you.

Comment: Stackoverflow as about _programming questions_. I don't think this is an on topic question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/416512/web-and-db-server-high-clock-rate-and-less-cores-vs-less-clock-rate-and-many on serverfault

Answer (score 3):

I don't agree on Microtechie's answer.

PHP executes a single request on one core only.
Probably most of the time not all cores are used.
If you have a higher clockspeed, requests finish faster, and the same core can process another request.

So my advise: focus on clock speed.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2267651/1339585

Answer (score 0):

There are two different situations that we can consider:

```
- One kind of processor that is just used for calculations for a single program.
```

In this situation, the Processor speed is more important as the user want the ability to do quickly and efficiently. Its not the case with web server.

```
- On the other hand the processor used for multiple programs running at the same time. ( concurrent processes)
```

The second is where multiple cores come in handy, as each program can be assigned to a separate core, thus freeing each program from 'bottle-necking' each other.

```
- From Intel :)
```

Software developers can no longer rely on increasing clock speeds alone to speed up single-threaded applications; instead, to gain a competitive advantage, developers must learn how to properly design their applications to run in a threaded environment. Multi-core architectures have a single processor package that contains two or more processor "execution cores," or computational engines, and deliver—with appropriate software—fully parallel execution of multiple software threads.

```
- In my opinion
```

Multi-core processors are good for multi-tasking and High speed processors are good for high performance applications. Most high performance applications, like 3D rendering and gaming, will eat up all the CPU power.

```
So you would need as many cores AND as much speed as possible.
```

Hope this explanation helps.