# Is their a way to insure that the load is close to evenly divided between the CPU's within each Apache/Drupal webserver?

Tags: apache, drupal

The CPU usage for the Test environment showed essentially all the usage on a single CPU (per server) and 0% usage on the all other CPUs for each Apache/Drupal webserver.

In production, there was also an imbalance observed, but while one CPU was at ~70% the others were around 15%.

Is their a way to insure that the load is close to evenly divided between the CPU's within each Apache/Drupal webserver?

Comment: I think there's no way for Apache (let alone Drupal) to determine which CPU core is used.

Comment: This must be done at OS level. Drupal, and for that matter Apache has nothing to do with it.

Comment: This question seems similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267345/how-do-you-make-good-use-of-multicore-cpus-in-your-php-mysql-applications