# Using Python's concurrent.futures to process objects in parallel

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, future, concurrent.futures

I just started using the library `concurrent.futures` from Python 3 to apply to a list of images a number of functions, in order to process these images and reshape them. 
The functions are `resize(height, width)` and `opacity(number)`.

On the other hand, I have the `images()` function that yield file-like objects, 
so I tried this code to process my images in parallel:

```
import concurrent.futures
From mainfile import images
From mainfile import shape


def parallel_image_processing :
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    future = executor.submit(images)
    for fileobject in future.result() :
        future1 = executor.submit( shape.resize, fileobject, "65","85")
        future2 = executor.submit( shape.opacity, fileobject, "0.5")
```

Could somebody tell if I am on the right path to accomplish this?

Comment: What's your question? You didn't state any problem with your current code. Except for telling you that that's not valid python syntax what do you expect?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what `images` returns? Is it just a list of open handles to file-like objects? You're probably going to run into issues reading from those file-like objects in parallel across two functions.

Comment: @Bakuriu my question was if it's the right way to process images in parallel in this case with python

Comment: @dano this is what images() returns :

yield open(os.path.join(image_dir[0], filename), 'rb')

Comment: @user1578720 So it's a generator then? Do `resize` and `opacity` expect just one file-like object to be passed to them or do they expect an iterable (like a generator)?

Comment: @dano they both expect one file-like object as an argument

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend making `images` just return a path, rather than an open file object:

```
def images():
    ...
    yield os.path.join(image_dir[0], filename)
```

And then using this:

```
from functools import partial

def open_and_call(func, filename, args=(), kwargs={}):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        return func(f, *args, **kwargs)

def parallel_image_processing():
    resize_func = partial(open_and_call, shape.resize, args=("65", "85"))
    opacity_func = partial(open_and_call, shape.opacity, args=("0.5"))
    img_list = list(images())
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        futures1 = executor.map(resize_func, img_list)
        futures2 = executor.map(opacity_func, img_list)

        concurrent.futures.wait([futures1, futures2])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Make sure the entry point to the function that creates the executor 
    # is inside an `if __name__ == "__main__"` guard if you're on Windows.
    parallel_image_processing()
```

If you're using CPython (as opposed to an alternative implementation that doesn't have a GIL, like Jython) you don't want to use `ThreadPoolExecutor`, because image processing is CPU-intensive; due to the GIL, only one thread can run at a time in CPython, so you won't actually do anything in parallel if you use threads for your use-case. Instead, use `ProcessPoolExecutor`, which will use processes instead of threads, avoiding the GIL altogether. Note that this is why I recommended not returning file-like objects from `images` - you can't pass an open file handle to the worker processes. You have to open the files in the workers instead.

To do this, we have our `executor` call a little shim function (`open_and_call`), which will open the file in the worker process, and then call the `resize`/`opacity` functions with the correct arguments.

I'm also using `executor.map` instead of `executor.submit`, so that we can call `resize`/`opacity` for every item returned by `images()` without an explicit for loop. I use `functools.partial` to make it easier to call a function taking multiple arguments with `executor.map` (which only allows you to call functions that take a single argument).

There's also no need to call `images()` in the executor, since you're going to wait for its results before continuing anyway. Just call it like a normal function. I convert the generator object returned by `images()` to a `list` prior to calling `map`, as well. If you're concerned about memory usage, you can call `images()` directly in each `map` call, but if not, it's probably faster to just call `images()` once and store it as a list.

Comment: [Not all implementations of Python use a GIL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3429159/190597), so it might be better to localize Python --> CPython.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it's very different from my original solution, can you tell if it may work the way i did it ? with some minor modifications ?

Comment: @user1578720 Your code will "work", but it won't really run in parallel, because you're using a `ThreadPoolExecutor`. You need to use a `ProcessPoolExecutor` to get real concurrency. And doing that requires changing `images` to return a file-name instead of a file object. But the way you're using `executor.submit` is correct.