# How can an interpretive language avoid using Global Interpreter lock (GIL)?

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, gil

CPython uses a [Global Interpreter Lock](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/api/threads.html).  Linux has removed all traces of the [Big Kernel Lock](http://kerneltrap.org/Linux/Removing_the_Big_Kernel_Lock).  What is the alternative to these locks?  How can a system make full use of a truly multi-core or multi-processor system without grinding everything to a halt?

Comment: C code (invoked from CPython) can run "full-threaded" as long as it doesn't need to grab the GIL -- it's only a restriction on the CPython engine. I'm not sure if Jython has similar restrictions.

Comment: Dupe of several of the articles under the Related column. Like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265687/why-the-global-interpreter-lock.

Comment: Jython and IronPython don't have the GIL.

Comment: @lacks Because they rely on the JVM and the CLR to handle threads.

Comment: @Rook The first answer on typo's link explain what the alternative to a GIL could be.

Comment: I don't understand the comparison of CPython with Linux. That's apples and oranges.

Comment: @David Heffernan  yes perhaps an apples thread and and oranges thread.

Comment: @Rook. Also read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991904/why-is-there-no-gil-in-the-java-virtual-machine-why-does-python-need-one-so-bad/991917#991917

Comment: @NullUserException  that is interesting.  This is why i asked this question.  To better understand new an upcoming interpreter technologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A GIL wouldn't be necessary if  python used a more advanced Garbage Collector like [IBM's Recycler](http://www.research.ibm.com/people/d/dfb/recycler.html) instated of a primitive reference counting method.  This is something that [Unladen Swallow](http://code.google.com/p/unladen-swallow/wiki/ProjectPlan#Global_Interpreter_Lock) is doing to improve the performance of python.  A more prommising answer is [Stackless Python](http://www.python.org/download/),  which uses its own micro-thread implementation instead of relying on the operating system like traditional CPython.

Comment: ...except that Unladen Swallow is dead, so no.

Comment: I added a comment, not an answer... the point is that someone could expect that CPython's GIL will go away sometime soon based on your answer.  It won't.

Comment: Would making python's reference counts atomic operations (via the appropriate assembly instructions) work also?  (I assume it's not that simple or they would have done it already)

Comment: Right, it was attempted with Unladen Swallow, but that has been pretty much abandoned. It seemed to be too much work so the developers went and created another language instead ([Go](http://golang.org/)).

Comment: @Keith  now that is interesting.

Comment: [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) is the new faster Python being developed with help of the creator of Psyco. It's over 3 times as fast as Unladen was, but not near Cython or Shed Skin: http://geetduggal.wordpress.com/2010/11/25/speed-up-your-python-unladen-vs-shedskin-vs-pypy-vs-c/

Answer (score 2):

The GIL is process specific, so you can get around it by launching several Python processes. The [multiprocessing module](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) provides an easy-to-use API for this.

Another way is to use C-extensions (or write your own) which release the GIL while doing the kind of data processing you need.

Comment: i'm asking how can an interpreter avoid using a gil.

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Have no mutable state, much like Haskell and other functional programming languages do. Since nothing in memory needs to be changed, no global lock is ever needed.

Comment: But GIL is for the implementation of interpreted languages, not the code in it, right? Haskell is usually compiled, and compilers can be in non-functional languages. Even if lists were banned and everyone had to use tuples in Python, it would still need garbage collection etc, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the GIL in quite the same way the Linux guys got rid of the Big Kernel Lock: simply add lots of more fine grained locks or use atomic primitives that don't need locks.

The downside and main reason Python doesn't do it, is performance. For example the Tcl interpreter has no GIL but can be compiled threaded and non-threaded, if you use the threaded version, you get around 10-20% less performance than in the single threaded case. So unless you use threads, it is actually slower. There have been Python patches to add smaller locks, but those had even worse performance impacts, so were rejected.

It is just a trade-off, the python devs decided that single thread performance (and backward compatibility with C-extensions) is much more important than the option to use many threads on the python level. You can still use threads freely inside a C-extension, just not meaningfully on the python language level.